# Single page website with SEO friendly ajax & history

Tags: ajax, seo, history.js, singlepage

I am busy building a single page website. The basic layout of the page is as follows - one section below the other:

- Header & Navigation
- Content Section 1 (example about us)
- Content Section 2 (example products)
- Content Section 3 (example clients)
- Footer

Each section will have a small menu inside it to ajax the content for the specific section. So Products section will have a product title menu, once clicked, product details will be ajaxed.

I can do these with normal techniques, but the problem is, I need the site to be SEO friendly, and indexed/crawled by Google.

I've never worked with it before, but history.js looks promising. I've done some testing, but can't find resources for my specific question. I am also open to other suggestions. All Ajaxed content will be separate HTML files - for SEO, hence the use of history.js sounding good to me.

**Specific Questions:**

- As the user scrolls down, passing each different section, the URL should
  change appropriately.
- The ajaxed content in each section should also change the URL.
- Google should be able to crawl the site an index the separate pages.
- I can change all of the content in a page with history.js, but is there a way to target my sections, so it only changes the content in my desired sections, instead of all content on the page?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using backbone.js.  Its depending on jquery and underscore.js.
It provides you the following features

- MVC architecture

  - It gives more structure to the client side code
- Templating

  - You can maintain templates in the client side which gives you a more organized code.
- URL re writing

  - Re-write urls on ajax calls. It Helps to develop SEO friendly website.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. That is definitely something I can look into. But that seems like a more long term investment. One which I am happy to do, but this project is under a deadline. So I fear I will not have enough time to learn a javascript framework such as backbone.js before my time runs out...

Comment: Backbone.js is very easy to learn.. It will take hardly 2 days..
Use this link. Its a very nice tutorial.. http://backbone.codeschool.com/